# How to put strings and numbers together in a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

**Difference from other questions**

Well first, I am a beginner, and I couldn't understand at least two questions. Secondly, one of the questions I looked at applied this concept in a completely new way. They had other variables and functions that were clouding my view of their code.

**Goal**

I am using SoloLearn as a C++ interpreter and I can't seem to get a string in a multidimensional array that has numbers in it. So I would appreciate you guys telling me what I need to fix so that there are no error messages when I run my code.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberArray [2] [3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, "null"}};
    return 0;
}
```

**Error message**

..\Playground: In function 'int main()':

..\Playground:6:57: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive] int numberArray [2] [3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, "null"}};

**Tries**

I have tried to change `int` into `string`, but this is what showed up on my screen: `Compilation error`. I don't want anything to show up on my screen. I also tried to change `int` into `bool`, but all that showed up was this: `No output.`.

Comment: Are you certain that the numbers should be actual numbers, or is it possible that they are text strings of numbers? I.e `char *numArray[2][3] = { {"1","2","3"}, {"4","5","null"} };` Perhaps if you could provide the text of or a link to the question, things would be clearer for those trying to help.

Comment: No, they have to be numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the reason that "string" does't work is that you're not including string as a package. Put

```
#include <string>;
```

below the other include directive

Secondly, I don't think you can mix types in C++

I agree with the approach you started on - making the multiD array "string"

load all as strings (i.e. load a 4 as "4")

When reading this array, check the entry in question using the C++ function atof

You'll need to include `#include <stdlib.h>`

atof will return a float if the ascii is a float number

otherwise will throw an exception

you can distinguish between numbers and text that way